# Deploy Kafka on AKS and able to test it

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, azure-aks

I have deployed Kafka & Zookeeper using "[https://medium.com/@*oleksii*/how-to-deploy-apache-kafka-cluster-zookeeper-in-kubernetes-c5b04f01ac20](https://medium.com/@_oleksii_/how-to-deploy-apache-kafka-cluster-zookeeper-in-kubernetes-c5b04f01ac20)"

I have used https://github.com/PharosProduction/tutorial-apache-kafka-cluster for the source code. I am able to test the Producer & Consumer internally with localhost:port and is working fine. When i am trying to use teh load balancer IP address, it does not work. Can someone please help me .

Comment: I suggest using Kafka operators https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator or https://github.com/banzaicloud/kafka-operator

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access services running inside your cluster, you need to expose them externally. Update the service type from `ClusterIP` to `LoadBalancer` in your service.yaml files. That should create a publicly accessible endpoint for your Kafka. You can see what the public IP address is by running `kubectl get services`.

You may need to update kafka service 2 and 3 to run on different ports (e.g. 9093,9094) in order to make them publicly accessible.

This method of running Kafka may not be very useful beyond testing purposes. None of the Kafka pods have persistent storage making your topics vulnerable to data loss.

Comment: Can you refer me someplace ... where i can get t his done..... I need to implement kafka on AKS and should be accessible via a LB which can be used by external producer & Consumer..... .Any reference pls

Comment: @nileshChaturvedi - please refer to: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer